# How to create multiple hotspots with hostapd?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, hostapd

I would like to create two hotspots with two SSIDs with hostapd (or, in case it's not directly possible, I can accept alternatives). They must share channel (since I only have one Wi-Fi adapter/antenna) but internally they should connect to different bridges (one of them I want to have as a limited network with special rules while the other should be just the pure Internet).

Assume I get Internet from eth0 and limited network from eth1. I would like the SSID "PI1" to be usable to connect to the same network as eth0 while "PI2" should connect to the same network as eth1. Of course, with proper security configurations, though I believe I can do that on my own as I have already a working config for one-SSID case. A complete dump:

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
ssid=PI
wpa_passphrase=PASSWORD
hw_mode=g
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
country_code=RO
channel=10
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Is it possible to do what I want? How should I go about it?

I would also like to actually have one of the SSIDs connected to a tunnel interface (OpenVPN client). I believe that would be a trivial change from a physical interface though.